# How to extract only numbers from string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like under mentioned in table in one column name remarks

```
Will0017,Will0018, Kind0045 , DGRG0012
```

I want to extract only numbers from the same only like 0017,0018,0045,0012

How can I do the same in mysql.

I have tried like this

```
select reject_remarks,regexp_substr(reject_remarks,"[0-9]+")  from table;
```

but have anything like I want

I have tried like this

```
select reject_remarks,regexp_substr(reject_remarks,"[0-9]+")  from table ;
```

Comment: Can you try with `REGEXP_REPLACE` and tell me whether it solves problem ?

Comment: `SELECT reject_remark, REGEXP_REPLACE(reject_remarks, '[^0-9]+', '') AS numbers
FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use REGEXP_REPLACE where ou negate all possible allowed characters

```
CREATE Table mytable(reject_remarks varchar(100))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('Will0017,Will0018, Kind0045 , DGRG0012')
```

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(reject_remarks, '[^0-9,[:space:]]+', '') AS numbers 
FROM mytable;
```

| numbers |
| --- |
| 0017,0018, 0045 , 0012 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rMnpAHug)

Answer (score 2):

You current query shall work fine as in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/TRq5YuEU)

```
select reject_remarks,regexp_substr(reject_remarks,"[0-9]+")  from mytable;
```

It might have so happened that, you have syntax error by using reserved keywords like `table`

Alternatively;
You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) in mysql for the same.

```
SELECT reject_remark, REGEXP_REPLACE(reject_remarks, '[^0-9]+', '') AS numbers 
FROM table_name;
```

This shall give you expected [output as in this DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/wIj19v7h)

```
reject_remarks  numbers
Will0017        0017
Will0018        0018
Kind0045        0045
DGRG0012        0012
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `regexp_substr`, you need to use the fourth parameter (see: [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr)):

```sql
select regexp_substr('Will0017,Will0018, Kind0045 , DGRG0012','[0-9]+',1,x)
from (select 1 as x union all select 2 union all 
      select 3 union all select 4)x;
```